# Вывод элементов .each

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток

Есть картинки

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="one.jpg" alt="один"/>
    <img src="two.jpg" alt="два"/>
    <img src="three.jpg" alt="три"/>
</div>
```

Вопрос: как при обработке при помощи .each,  значение атрибута alt первой картинки вывести последним, а вывод начать со второго элемента? 
Код как вы понимаете не совсем живой и не стоит сильно обращать внимание на правильность его написания. Я написал такой код

```
$('#slider img').each(funktion(){
    $(this).attr('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переставьте элемент в конец массива до обработки:

```
Arr.push(Arr.shift());
```

Comment: к сожалению я шибся это не массив, а объект.

Comment: Куда вы хотите выводить значение атрибутов alt?

Comment: да хоть алертом дело в том что пишет TypeError: arr.shift is not a function
 

arr =arr.push(arr.shift());

Comment: Можно так http://jsfiddle.net/bha6Ljx3/

Comment: не совсем то но за index  спасибо за то и ставлю ответ

Answer (score -1):

Сохранение 1го значения во временную переменную + условный оператор

```
var tmp, i=0;
$.each(Arr, function(key,val){
    if(i=0){tmp=val;}else{console.log(val);} 
     i++;
});
console.log(tmp);
```

(для простого массива можно и key использовать вместо i, но, если ты сделвешь `var Arr=[]; Arr['a']=1; Arr['b']=1;` key=0 у тебя никогда не получится)